# Checking form input for text and changing it's color

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

Here I have a problem which I can't get over with. This is the code and I want the script to change the form input's color when the entered text changes:

```
function checkName(name)
{
if (name.value == "value1" || name.value == "value2" || name.value == "value3" || name.value == "value4" || name.value == "value5" || name.value == "value6"){
 document.forms['un'].elements['name'].style.color='#ffbb00'
}
else {
 document.forms['un'].elements['name'].style.color='#000000'
}
}
```

As you can see when the entered text matches with one of the provided ones, it should turn orange, and when not, it shall be black. (I have an input toggling this function with an onChange thing)
I just can't make it work so I can have multiple choices on when to change color, and also change back when the statement becomes invalid. Any help?

Comment: Can you post your full code, please, perhaps in a jsFiddle?

Comment: I haven't really read any source material to verify this, but shouldn't you be passing an integer to `document.forms[]` rather than a string `'un'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I have an input toggling this function with an onChange thing` so your Input

```
<input type=text size=20 name='name' onchange="checkName(this)">
```

and function could be

```
function checkName(el)
{
    if (el.value == "value1" || el.value == "value2" || el.value == "value3" || el.value == "value4" || el.value == "value5" || el.value == "value6")
    {
        el.style.color='#ffbb00'
    }
    else
    {
        el.style.color='#000000'
    }
}
```

[**An example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/F3SQC/1/)

You may also try `onkeyup` like [**this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/F3SQC/2/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
function checkName(element) {
    if (element.value == ...) {
        element.className = "inputError";
    } else {
        element.className = "";
    }
}
```

Then in your CSS file:

```
.inputError {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    background-image: url(exclamation_mark.png);
    background-position: right 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
}
```

Now that you have predefined CSS styles of the input boxes, everytime you check the input box you can set it to the appropriate CSS class name.

Now all you have to do is this:

```
<input id="myTextBox" type="text" onkeyup="javascript: checkName(this);" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: A bit too complicated I think.

Comment: The problem was with yours I couldn't fit the code you provided into my page correctly (maybe because I just started web programming), so don't take this as anything bad, the other one I accepted had a piece of code I was able to implement very easily, but this doesn't mean yours is not good. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You assume that the value in the textbox is automatically passed in to the function checkName.  I believe that this is your mistake.

You can refer to the value in the textbox within your function `checkName` using `event.srcElement.value`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution:  http://jsfiddle.net/QJG5R/1/

Code dump:

```
var input = document.getElementById('blar');
var highlights = {
    'v':'#888888',
    'va':'#666699',
    'val':'#4444aa',
    'valu':'#2222bb',
    'value':'#0000cc',    
    'value1':'#ff0000',
    'value2':'#00ff00'
};
input.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    var value = input.value;
    if (highlights[value]) {
        input.style.color = highlights[value];
    } else {
        input.style.color = 'black';
    }    
});​
```

Html contains a single element:
`<input id='blar' type='text' />​`